# Ocaml - Same Random.int

Tags: random, ocaml

I have a problem with the module Random.int in Ocaml.

So I have a program with for example :

```
let a : int = Random.int 100;;
-> val a : int = 44
```

The problem is that when I launch the program with emacs and I run it with ctrl-c ctrl-b, I have every time the same result.

I have already test to put Random.self_init or Random.full_init in the top of the program but it's also the same result.

Thanx for helping me

There is my code : https://github.com/leofrk2/ocaml_ex_9.ml/blob/master/ex_9.ml
( Run it on emacs ) 
Maybe I have an error anywhere with random.

Edit : The error was that I put only one time Random.self_init (). Program works !

Comment: It should work with `Random.self_init`. Particularly with `/dev/urandom` installed (do you have it?). `Random.self_init` is deterministic based on the seed though, so that was not going to work.

Comment: Yes /dev/unradom is installed.

Ok so I need to use Random.full_init ? With these two option, no one works..

Comment: The simplest way would be `ls /dev/urandom` (note you misspelled it in your comment). And no, if you don't want "the same result" each time you run it, then `Random.full_init` is of no use. For that purpose you should use `Random.self_init`, which should work better if you have `/dev/urandom` (but is supposed to work anyway).

Comment: It's weird.. /dev/urandom is present, and I use Random.self_init and I have every time the same result.. I don't understand :/

Comment: It works for me. Maybe try it in the shell directly, rather than via emacs. It should return a different result each time you load it via `#use "file.ml";;`

Comment: I have test this solution but it give me the same result.
Maybe is there a solution where I can show you the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the only real possibility is that `Random.self_init` isn't actually being executed. So that's what I would verify.

```
# Random.self_init ();;
- : unit = ()
# Random.int 100;;
- : int = 62
# Random.self_init ();;
- : unit = ()
# Random.int 100;;
- : int = 79
```

Comment: Hey, 
Could you look my code and say me why it doesn't work ? 
I think there is a error with the generation of random var but I didn't see where.. 

Thanks you !

Comment: My bad, the error is that I put Random.self_init () only one time..
Thanks you a lot !

Comment: You should only call `self_init ()` once by program: seeding the random generator is possibly an expansive operation that you don't want to repeat more than necessary.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't realize what you were saying. You don't want to call `Random.self_init` before every call to `Random.int`. My example is just to illustrate that `Random.self_init ()` does a different initialization each time. If you call it (once) you will get a different random sequence afterwards. Just make sure you are really calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function as follows:

```
Random.self_init ()
```

In the code you shared, there is:

```
Random.full_init;;
```

If you evaluate this on the repl, here is the output:

```
- : int array -> unit = <fun>
```

You are only taking the value of `Random.full_init`, which is a function, and not calling it.